# Confusion over running methods on Class Method instances of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, singleton

So I'm getting myself into a confusion over where my data's going and where it's stored in my application. It's not a specific question so hopefully someone can provide a generalised answer.

I need to pass some data around between a few `UIViewController` instances, and I'm currently doing that with a singleton object called my dataManager. This class has one method, a class method, called `+ (LCDataManager *) sharedDataManager`, and that method basically checks if whether the `sharedDataManager` already exists, if so, return it, if not, create it and set up its variables. This means that I can refer to that class anywhere I like, access and modify its variables anywhere I like, from across multiple classes.

First question: is this the correct / best / most appropriate means of passing data around like this? I'm hoping it obeys MVC, it feels like it does, and I hope I'm right.

Second question: what if I want to put an instance method in that class, and call it from within the class method? Let's say my `sharedDataManager` needs to call a method to grab some objects one of its variables (an array), and put them in another array, then send that back out again. I can't do that, can I? What's the way around that? If I make an instance of that class (rather than using the shared instance), I lose the ability to use that instance across multiple viewControllers.

I'm hideously confused, and it seems like it's not the problem I'm making it. Appreciate any guidance, and preferably not that "Read the Apple documentation" stuff – they write as if you already know what you're doing, and frankly I don't yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First question: is this the correct / best / most appropriate means of passing data around like this? I'm hoping it obeys MVC, it feels like it does, and I hope I'm right.

Your design is perfectly MVC compliant.

> Second question: what if I want to put an instance method in that class, and call it from within the class method?

you can surely define an instance method and call it like this:

```
[[MyModelClass sharedModel] myInstanceMethod];
```

indeed, `[MyModelClass sharedModel]` will give you an *instance* of `MyModelClass` (which should be guaranted to be unique being it a singleton).

If you want to call the instance method from the `sharedModel` class method, you could also do that, because `sharedModel` owns a reference to your singleton, so it can send messages to it.

Answer (score 3):

> is this the correct / best / most appropriate means of passing data around like this?

There's nothing wrong with only having a single instance of LCDataManager, but using the Singleton pattern [has potential problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what/40610#40610). An alternative is to just initialize one LCDataManger and to pass it around to wherever it's needed.

> what if I want to put an instance method in that class, and call it from within the class method?

The accessor `+ (LCDataManager *) sharedDataManager` should only return the instance. I guess what you want is something like

```
+ (LCDataManager *)preparedDataManager {
    LCDataManager *shared = [self sharedDataManager];
    [shared doSomeInstanceMagic];
    return shared;
}

- (void)doSomeInstanceMagic {
    // magic!
    // grab some objects one of its variables (an array),
    // and put them in another array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Matthijs Hollemans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411775/hollance) has an excellent three-part tutorial on his blog about the correct way to make your view controllers talk to each other:

- [Part 1](http://www.hollance.com/2011/04/making-your-classes-talk-to-each-other-part-1/)
- [Part 2](http://www.hollance.com/2011/04/making-your-classes-talk-to-each-other-part-2/)
- [Part 3](http://www.hollance.com/2011/04/making-your-classes-talk-to-each-other-part-3/)

Comment: @lukech You're welcome. Please note that the usual way to say thank you on Stack Overflow is with an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with this development architecture, and it is the must used (I think) in the iOS development. In the book [IOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_) they call it *Model View Controller Store*.

Regarding your second question, yes, you can declare instance methods and call then from your `sharedDataManager`. What is not usual is creating other instances of a singleton class, but it is possible.